# When should / shouldn't we serialize a class in Spark?

Tags: serialization, apache-spark

I have a class that reads from a file in HDFS and tries to create a graph from that. I do some transformations on the file in the class initialization that don't work unless I make the class serializable.

```
class GraphLoader(path:String, sc:SparkContext)
  extends java.io.Serializable {

  val records = sc.textFile(path).map(x => x.split(",")).filter(x => x(0) == "1" || x(0) == "2")
  records.cache()

  val people:RDD[(Long,PersonProperty)] = records.
    flatMap(line => List(line(1).safeToLong, line(4).safeToLong)).
    map(number => (number, PersonProperty("default")))
...
```

.safeToLong is basically a method I defined in an implicit class that I use to convert Strings to Longs and deal with any Exceptions that I encounter.

It won't run without the Serializable extension and I'm bothered because I feel like it's a pretty heavy thing to pass. Is there a better/more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Spark is an engine for distributed (cluster) computing, which inherently requires communication among different nodes (JVMs). This communication in turn requires serialization, because every time a class or object leaves its JVM, it must be serialized.

The bottom line is that most of the Spark code you write will need to be serializable. Any code that isn't cannot take advantage of the distributed nature of Spark. You should [tune](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization) the serialization to optimize your Spark application.